# GKE ingress-gce detaches the newly created network endpoint when a new rule is added

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am seeing some weird behavior with GKE ingress-gce, everytime I add a new host/path rule to the ingress it tries to attach the network endpoint first and then detaches with no reasoning like shown in the screen shot. If I apply the ingress configuration again the backend is added properly.

How can I know why the network endpoint is being detached? Why do I have to apply the same configuration twice?

[image]

Comment: By add a new rule you mean add a new host/path rule ?

Comment: yup! editing the question

Comment: @s_curry_s are you changing any port mapping related configs along with your hostPath configs..?